# Match a simple Regex

Tags: grep, regular-expression, ack

I need to match this: (tt\d{1,10}) in a file with the file ending txt.

I have tried grep and ack-grep but without results.

```
ack-grep -G \.txt$ -g "(tt\d{1,10})"
```

Comment: Can you specify whether these  **(tt\d{1,10})** are meant to be literals, or a regex? In the latter case you need to use grep w/ **-E** ...

Comment: Few command-line regex engines honor `\d` for `[0-9]`. Is that what you intend? You can use `\{...\}` instead of `{...}` if you use basic regex (no `-E`).

Comment: It looks like the documentation does not specify which type of regex is used. The `\d` is a PCRE extension (also used by other implementations) that are not found in BRE (default regular grep) or ERE (egrep). In BRE the `{}` characters must be escaped. The `()` characters also need to be escaped for grouping in BRE.

Comment: So in short, you could try the pattern `tt[0-9]\{1,10\}`.

Comment: @dubiousjim that pattern worked. But using this `ack-grep tt[0-9]\{1,10\} *.nfo` command will only search the current dir. How can I get it to search recursive?

Comment: That's because you gave up on both the g/G flags  **ack-grep -g 'tt[0-9]\{1,10\}' -G ".nfo"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `find` for this kind of thing, and get it to execute `grep` on matching files. Using @dubiousjim's regex from above:

```
find ./ -name "*.txt" -exec grep -Hn --color=auto 'tt[0-9]\{1,10\}' {} \;
```

**Update**
Sorry to bloat this, but I felt I should return and explain the options in further detail...
The above `find` command is essentially two separate commands, rolled into one with the '-exec' option.

This first bit I hope is fairly self-explanatory:-
`find ./ -name "*.txt"`

But find's `-exec` sub-command has it's own special syntax. 
`{}` is specific to `find` and its `-exec` option, as is `\;`. `{}` is replaced with the full matching path name, and the `\;` signifies the end of the command line arguments for the exec'd program, which in this case is `grep`.

`grep -Hn --color=auto 'regex' {} \;`

I use these options in an attempt to replicate the appearance of `grep -r`, by printing with colours, line numbers (`-n`) and file name (`-H`) for each matched expression.
Note that alias's don't work within commands exec'd by `find`, which is why I add `'--color=auto'` manually.

Comment: Awesome thanks. Here is what I ended up with: `find ./ -name "*.txt" -exec grep -o 'tt[0-9]\{1,10\}' {} \;`

Answer (score 5):

With `ack-grep`, looks like you were looking for

```
ack-grep -uhoG '\.txt$' 'tt\d{1,10}'
```

Which would be more or less the equivalent of the `find` command you "ended up with", which, by the way can be optimised to:

```
find . -name '*.txt' -exec grep -Eo 'tt[0-9]{1,10}' {} +
```

to avoid having to run one `grep` command per txt file.

You may also want to consider adding a `-type f` to avoid having to search the text in directories or symlinks or devices... (though I'll agree it's rare (except for symlinks) for them to have `*.txt` name).

Also note that the `-o` option to `grep` is GNU specific and GNU grep also has a `-r` option to recursively search into directories, but beware that older versions of GNU grep descend into symlinks to directories, so using `find` is generally better/safer if you don't have a recent `grep`.